# Qt QProcess sometimes works and sometimes does not work

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qprocess

I want to convert a `ps` file to `pdf` by `ps2pdf` and this codes in Qt:

```
QPixmap graphPng(filePath +  "report/pictures/graph-000.png");
int graphPsWidth=graphPng.width();
int graphPsHeight=graphPng.height();

//convert "ps" file to "pdf" file
QProcess process;
QStringList arg;
arg<<"-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=" + QString::number(graphPsWidth)<<"-dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=" + QString::number(graphPsHeight)<<"export/report/pictures/graph-000.ps"<<"export/report/pictures/graph-000.pdf";
process.start("ps2pdf",arg);
//process.waitForStarted(-1);
process.waitForFinished(-1);
```

(I use a `png` file as the same dimensions of the `ps` file to get the dimensions and use it in creating `pdf` file)

I don't know why sometimes the `pdf` file is created and some times without any output message (`process::readAllStandardError()` and `process::readAllStandardOutput()`) there is no `pdf` file!

When  the `pdf` file is not created if I run that immediately in terminal, the `pdf` file will be created!!!

What is the reason and how can I solve it?

Comment: what is `filePath`?

Comment: @eyllanesc `filePath` is `export/` folder

Comment: Where is the executable of your program?

Comment: @eyllanesc my `build` folder is consist of: executable of my program and `export` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve the problem by handling the RAM, because if the ram exceed the specific limit (almost near the full capacity of the RAM), the `QProcess` can not be started. So every time it diagnoses the exceeded limit, the `PDF` file is not created and vice versa.

Comment: How did you solve the issue? I'm facing the similar issue.. When the parent process has some memory usage. QProcess cannot fork giving not enough memory error while looking the stack trace

Answer (score 1):

It is always advisable to verify all the steps, so I share a more robust version of your code.

For example it is not necessary to use `QPixmap`, the correct thing is to use `QImage`. In addition, the path of the files is verified.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDir>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QImage>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDir directory(QString("%1%2%3")
                   .arg(a.applicationDirPath())
                   .arg(QDir::separator())
                   .arg("export/report/pictures/"));

    QString name = "graph-000";
    QString png_path = directory.filePath(name + ".png");
    QString ps_path = directory.filePath(name + ".ps");

    // verify path
    Q_ASSERT(QFileInfo(png_path).exists());
    Q_ASSERT(QFileInfo(ps_path).exists());

    QString pdf_path = directory.filePath(name+".pdf");

    QImage img(png_path);
    int graphPsWidth = img.width();
    int graphPsHeight = img.height();

    QProcess process;
    QStringList arg;
    arg << QString("-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=%1").arg(graphPsWidth) <<
         QString("-dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=%1").arg(graphPsHeight) <<
         ps_path << pdf_path;

    process.start("ps2pdf",arg);
    process.waitForFinished();
    Q_ASSERT(QFileInfo(pdf_path).exists());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but now some times, `Q_ASSERT(QFileInfo(pdf_path).exists())` force the program to be closed. It means that the `pdf` file is not exist.

Comment: @mortezaaliahmadi So I recommend you check your ps2pdf, what version of ghostscript do you have ?, I've tested it in a loop of 100 iterations and it works correctly. 
I have tested it with ghostscript 9.23

Comment: I think the problem is `QProcess` instead of `ps2pdf` because in another part of my program I start `latex` command in `QProcess` again and I have some times a latex file and some times not.

Comment: @mortezaaliahmadi Well, I tested it with Qt 5.10.1 and it works correctly.

Comment: I think QProcess may have a cache that should be cleared or some thing like this.

Comment: thanks @eyllanesc, I can solve the problem. Please see my answer to question.